# How to apply sorting(ascending and descending) in AngularJs where we get data inside table

Tags: angularjs, sorting

**Dates i receive from server in below format**

```
    30-Nov-2015 10:54:19 AM 
    30-Nov-2015 10:54:19 AM 
    03-Dec-2015 10:54:19 AM   
    02-Dec-2015 10:54:19 AM   
    01-Dec-2015 10:54:19 AM
```

Comment: It should sort as per the date the data received.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data before adding to the table. There are multiple ways to sort an array of dates.

- using Javascript array native methods. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp You can use moment.js http://momentjs.com/ to get the time difference easily.

  - you can also use _lodash sortBy. https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Answer (score 0):

if your field is called 'date' the you can sort like so:

in your Ctrl:

```
 $scope.dates =
      [{date: new Date('30-Nov-2015 10:54:19 AM')},
       {date: new Date('30-Nov-2015 10:54:19 AM')},
       {date: new Date('03-Dec-2015 10:54:19 AM')},
       {date: new Date('02-Dec-2015 10:54:19 AM')},
       {date: new Date('01-Dec-2015 10:54:19 AM')}];


  $scope.predicate = 'date';
```

View:

```
<table>
  <tr>      
    <th>
      <a href="" ng-click="order('date')">date</a>
      <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'date'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="date in dates | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <td>{{date.date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:a'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0Kxe7x9hOahDgdECMi7?p=preview).

You may want to read the Angular docs for [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: Hey Jax,    Ascending order sort   = 02-Dec-2015 / 01-Dec-2015 / 30-Nov-2015 and   Desending order sort  = 30-Nov-2015 / 01-Dec-2015 /02-Dec-2015.   This way the sort should happen which is not happening in your plunkr answer.Can you please check it again

Comment: Hey, that's sorted now, just transformed the dates you get back from server to new Date objects. Hope it helps